# Jedi-vim sometimes not showing the autocompletion list.

Tags: python, vim, autocomplete, jedi

I just installed Jedi-vim in my built in vim on Mac.
I had the 
`let g:pymode_rope = 0`
And everything looks fine except it is not showing the list for autocompletion while I can still see the documentation and can switch between different options (while i cant see those option list)
Here is a picture.
[image]

As you can see, there is the documentation for List.append and I can switch to other options as well, but i cannot see the whole autocompletion list.
Could anyone give me any suggestion about this?
Thanks!

Comment: It is a bit off topic, but I tried the same: installed jedi to better work with vim. Finally I still had a lot of issues like yours (had to restart vim to get completion again). After a little bit of time I tried something else. I tried Eclipse with Pydev and Vrapper, and even if I still lack some of my favorite features of Vim, I can at least use basic normal mode features. The debugger I have now is also very nice thing that I hadn't had the time to look at in Vim. You may want to try a setting with Eclipse to see the difference...

Comment: Thanks for the tips! The best Python IDE is PyCharm in my opinion :) However, there are times when I have to use some vim.

Comment: If you can select other suggestions with `<Up>`/`<Down>` you probably have a colorscheme issue.

Comment: Hi @romainl I thought about the same thing, but the autocompletion list actually shows every now and then...

Comment: @Koshien Still, try to disable the color scheme for a while and then report back again.